# Linking Google analytics and Python

Tags: python, mysql, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am doing a project on digital analytics using Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics in which I am struck at one point. In my project I am tracking data of a website and after that I want to push the tracked data to MySQL database. I want to use Python language to do this job. My question is how to design database schema for my project? Anyone please help me with python code

Comment: What point are you specifically stuck at? Do you need an API for data extraction? Do you need a particular format of data? What type of Google Analytics account are you working with (is it a premium 360 account)?

Comment: I am not able to decide whether I should have a single table with many columns for all the metrics being tracked by GA OR one table each for specific metric. For example lets say I have two metrics clicks and page views. Should I create single table with two columns namely clicks and page views OR two tables ( One table with column clicks and another table with column page views). Hope I am clear. Also I am not using premium 360 account.

Comment: When you say clicks, do you mean Ecommerce Product Clicks or Events?

Comment: Not specifically product or events. By clicks I mean clicking on URL and buttons on a web page.

Comment: But with respect to how Google Analytics captures the data, how is it storing it? I ask because different types of interactions can be aggregated together. For example sessions and pages do not work together.